# \newcommand inside a tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, nodes

In this example

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning, calc}
\newcommand{\element}[1]{[draw, rectangle] {#1}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [align=center](a) 
          [draw, rectangle]{a};
  \node [align=center, anchor = north](b) at ($(a.south) + (0, -0.3)$) 
          [draw, rectangle]{b};
  \node [align=center, anchor = west](c) at ($(a.east) + (0.3, 0)$)        
          \element{c};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

at node `c` I try to use `\newcommand` `\element` that should construct node `c` in the same way as nodes `a` and `b` are constructed.

Is such an approach possible? Assume I need to construct multiple nodes in a repetitive and nontrivial way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you should define a tikz style for nodes:

**for one argument**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning, calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
element/.style={draw,rectangle,node contents=#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [align=center](a) 
          [draw, rectangle]{a};
  \node [align=center, anchor = north](b) at ($(a.south) + (0, -0.3)$) 
          [draw, rectangle]{b};
  \node [align=center, anchor = west,element=c,at={($(a.east) + (0.3, 0)$)}] ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**for 3 arguments**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning, calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
element/.style n args={3}{draw=#2,shape=#3,node contents=#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [align=center](a) 
          [draw, rectangle]{a};
  \node [align=center, anchor = north](b) at ($(a.south) + (0, -0.3)$) 
          [draw, rectangle]{b};
  \node [align=center, anchor = west,element={c}{blue}{rectangle},name=c,at={($(a.east) + (0.3, 0)$)}] ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to change `element=c` if I have more than 1 argument to element?

Comment: I will reedit my answer considering your new requirement soon